# Check if value exists in external file array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code which is to check if google exist in the external array file, it gives me the blank result but when i transferred the array into the same file or inline the list, it works. I'm using the external array file for global use.

```
$approveurl = file('../webfilters.php');
if(in_array('http://google.com', $approveurl)){ echo "Success";}
```

Comment: what is the external array file ?

Comment: The external array file looks like this

vergleich-webhosting.info
alltemplate.org
executivestudio.net

Comment: you want to check the html code of this sites to see if there is the string `http://google.com` ?

Comment: Yes, the file() code returns the external file into array when i use the var_dump($approveurl) it will show the list into array form.

Comment: At a minimum you need to use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag, otherwise all the strings in the array will end with newline, so they won't match.

Comment: as far as I know in_array checks if you have one complete element in the "haysack" that is equal to the "needle" . for such things I would use file_get_contents and then you use strpos($needle, $haysack)

Comment: Okay, Thank you for this help, i added the code and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to turn the file into an array. Read it into a string and then use `strstr()`.

```
$data = file_get_contents("../webfilters.php");
if (strstr($data, "http://google.com")) {
    echo "Success";
}
```